# Simplest way to implement user login / authentication in Python

Tags: python, frameworks, authentication

I'm developing a fairly simple Python web app and I want to allow users to log in. I know the solution will probably involve installing some sort of framework rather than doing it in straight Python and I'm OK with that, I'm just wondering, what would be the easiest, most hassle-free way to add authentication? The app is already written in straight Python so any extra code I use will only be used to for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Store the user's login, the *salted hash* of their password, and the salt in a database. (If you're going for cryptographic overkill, you can use a very expensive-to-compute hashing algorithm like `bcrypt`.)

You can use [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sqlite3.html) as that's bundled with Python, but it would probably make more sense to install a database separately and use that.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use SHA256.